# Is it possible to inject IHttpClientFactory to a strongly typed client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

As the heading tells.

Let's say I register a strongly typed client like

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

//A named client is another option that could be tried since MSDN documentation shows that being used when IHttpClientFactory is injected.
//However, it appears it gives the same exception.
//services.AddHttpClient("test", httpClient => 
services.AddHttpClient<TestClient>(httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("");                    
});
.AddHttpMessageHandler(_ => new TestMessageHandler());

//Registering IHttpClientFactory isn't needed, hence commented.
//services.AddSingleton(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>());
var servicesProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);

public class TestClient
{
    private IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory { get; }
    public TestClient(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        ClientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAsync(CancellationToken cancellation = default)
    {
        //using(var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("test")) 
        using(var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient())
        {
            return await client.GetAsync("/", cancellation);
        }
    }
}

// This throws with "Message: System.InvalidOperationException : A suitable constructor
// for type 'Test.TestClient' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services
// are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

var client = servicesProvider.GetService<TestClient>();
```

But as noted in the comments, an exception will be thrown. Do I miss something bovious or is this sort of an arrangement not possible?

<edit: If `IHttpClientFactory` is registered, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown while trying to resolve `client`. Strange, strange.

<edit 2: The scenario I'm thinking to avoid is described and discussed also at https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/924 and maybe the way written there is one, perhaps not as satisfactory, way of avoiding some problems.

This happens in a XUnit project, probably doesn't have anything to do with the problem, but who knows. :)

<edit 3: A console program to show the problem.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TypedClientTest
{

public class TestClient
{
    private IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory { get; }

    public TestClient(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        ClientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> TestAsync(CancellationToken cancellation = default)
    {
        using (var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient())
        {
            return await client.GetAsync("/", cancellation);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services
            .AddHttpClient<TestClient>(httpClient => httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.github.com/"));

        var servicesProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);

        //This throws that there is not a suitable constructor. Should it?
        var client = servicesProvider.GetService<TestClient>();
    }
}
}
```

with `install-package Microsoft.Extensions.Http` and `install-package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

Also in the exception stack there reads

> at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory`1.Cache.get_Activator()
>      at ** Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory`1.CreateClient(HttpClient httpClient) **
>      at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory`1.Cache.get_Activator()
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory`1.CreateClient(HttpClient httpClient)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>      at TypedClientTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projektit\testit\TypedClientTest\TypedClientTest\Program.cs:line 40

which of course points towards the problem. But needs probably further debugging.

<edit 4: So going to the source, the problem is visible at https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/557995ec322f1175d6d8a72a41713eec2d194871/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory.cs#L47 and in https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/11cf90103841c35cbefe9afb8e5bf9fee696dd17/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs in general.

There are probably some ways to go about this now. :)

<edit 5:

So it appears calling `.AddHttpClient` for a typed client that has `IHttpClientFactory` one ends up in a "weird place". And indeed, it's not possible to use `IHttpClientFactory` to create a typed client of its own type.

One way of making this with named client could be something like

```
public static class CustomServicesCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IHttpClientBuilder AddTypedHttpClient<TClient>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Action<HttpClient> configureClient)  where TClient: class
    {
        //return serviceCollection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(TClient).Name, f => new ...,*/ ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
        servicesCollection.AddTransient<TClient>();
        return serviceCollection.AddHttpClient(typeof(TType).Name, configureClient);
    }
}

public static class HttpClientFactoryExtensions
{
    public static HttpClient CreateClient<TClient>(this IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        return clientFactory.CreateClient(typeof(TClient).Name);
    }
}


public class TestClient
{
    private IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory { get; }

    public TestClient(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        ClientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Test(CancellationToken cancellation = default)
    {
        using(var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient<TestClient>())
        {
            return await client.GetAsync("/", cancellation);
        }
    }
}
```

Which mimicks what the extension methods already do. It's of course now possible to expose the lifetime services better too.

Comment: Did you register an instance of `IHttpClientFactory`?

Comment: Ah, yes, good point. I added a line for `services.AddSingleton(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>());` so yes, but could be wrong perhaps? I had it, just accidentally removed while copy-pasting code.

Comment: You don't need to register `IHttpClientFactory`. That's done by `AddHttpClient`. Besides, you're not even doing it right. First, you're attempting to register it by pulling out of the service collection, which would of course fail, if it's not already registered (circular logic). Second, you cannot register an interface as a service. There has to be a concrete implementation.

Comment: So when not attempting to do it, the exception in the code comments, `InvalidOperationException` gets thrown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read about [Typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#typed-clients):

> A typed client accepts a HttpClient parameter in its constructor

Instead of `IHttpClientFactory` your class should accept an `HttpClient` in its constructor, which will be provided by DI (enabled with the `AddHttpClient` extension).

```
public class TestClient
{
    private HttpClient Client { get; }
    public TestClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAsync(CancellationToken cancellation = default)
    {
        return client.GetAsync("/", cancellation);
    }
}
```

### Edit

(based on above edits)

If you want to override the default behavior of the `AddHttpClient` extension method, then you should register your implementation directly:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddHttpClient("test", httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost");                    
});

services.AddScoped<TestClient>();

var servicesProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);
using (var scope = servicesProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var client = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestClient>();
}
```

```
public class TestClient
{
    private IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory { get; }

    public TestClient(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        ClientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAsync(CancellationToken cancellation = default)
    {
        using (var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("test"))
        {
            return client.GetAsync("/", cancellation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Maybe I need to dig into the code to see what is the problem. The scenario I'm thinking to avoid is described and discussed also at https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/924 and maybe the way written there is one, perhaps not as satisfactory, way of avoiding some problems.

Comment: Further, the document alludes that using named client would work when injecting `IHttpClientFactory` while it appears I run into the same exception. I'll update the question.

Comment: I don't want to override the default behavior. I wonder why injecting `IHttpClientFactory` to typed client constructor throws an exception when trying to resolve it. Even when I use just named client as in the documented example you linked the result is an exception. I'm doing that in a test project currently, but maybe I need to create a standalone console program and have it linked/pasted here (with package versions).

Comment: I accepted your answer, closen enough. :) Thanks for being mindful for my "public debugging" while I tried to air my thoughts with this amongst a bazillion other things.